# Custom Footer not showing in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, footer, footer-links

I am creating custom footer to show the **5 Columns** footer with **2 Rows**. In first row to showing the `CMS` links and second row like copyrights and logs. for that I have written below code. But it is not showing. Even though I have executed `php bin/magento cache:clean` and `php bin/magento cache:flush`.

**CustomFooter/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="store.settings.language" remove="true"/>

        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo.png</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">40</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <container name="footer-top" label="Footer Top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-top page-main">
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block-footertop">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block-footertop</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>

            <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer container">
                <remove name="form.subscribe"/>
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="html/copyright.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="report.bugs" template="Magento_Theme::html/bugreport.phtml" />
            </container>

        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
        <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

But it is not showing. Any help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="store.settings.language" remove="true"/>

        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo.png</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">40</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

         <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
           <container name="footer-top" label="Footer Top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-top page-main">
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block-footertop">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block-footertop</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>


        <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true"/>


        <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
        <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: If I want to remove default links how? In my case only show my custom footer.

Comment: use this code  `<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>`

Comment: news letter not removing. I have tried `<referenceBlock name="footer.newsletter" remove="true"/>` Is it correct?

Comment: Use this code `<referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true"/>`

Comment: If I want to show **newsletter subscriber** in my custom `.phtml` file `<?php /** @var  \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer $block */ ?>  <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.subscribe'); ?>` Is it correct way to get the data? I am write this but not getting.

Comment: use code ` <?php echo $block->getChildHtml() ?>`